# Repeatedly showing two pictures in a random order

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and have therefore a rather simple question.

I guess it should be possible to show two different pictures 50 times. Let’s say two different colored circles, in an random order for a second or until the user presses a certain key, but I have no idea how to start. Is there an easy way?

Maybe it's easier to start with a list of actions (either showing circle a or showing circle b) and randomly choosing one of it like the following modified code from a different question:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

        actions.Add(() => Program.circleA());
        actions.Add(() => Program.circleB());

        Random random = new Random();

        int selectedAction = random.Next(0, actions.Count()); // What does this line do?

        actions[selectedAction].Invoke(); // And this one?
    }
```

Afterwards I have to define what Program.circleA and Program.circleB does, right?

Should I implement this in a loop? If yes, how do I specify that each circle has to be shown 50 times before the breakout criteria is met?

I've search the Internet for similar problems, but I couldn't find a solution or maybe just couldn't understand them, so that's why I'm asking you guys and girls :)

Comment: Lets start with the basics... do you want to use WinForms, WPF or some other GUI framework? Personally I'd recommend WPF, but others may have a different oppinion on this matter. However, you state that you are new to programming. Depending on how new "new" is, you might be better of writing a few more console applications before moving on to GUI and then write a new simple GUI applications where you display images, before trying to make the image show timing-based and randomly.

Comment: well i want to keep it very basic and on a low level with WinForms. I thought it'b be rather simple to show either a red circle or yellow one and count the times the user presses a certain key.

Comment: Point is: you should first try to display one circle without any fancy extras. When you succeed you can move on to two circles and to other additional functionality. But your current code doesn't show the basics, so a potential answer would need to cover many unrelated things that should belong to different questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your question is basically "How can I call a random action/method?" and "Is my logic of doing that okay?".

Starting with the second one (because it's easier), the answer will be the same as the answer to this simple question: "Is it doing its job?". Meaning if your logic is behaving like you wanted to, the answer is yes. If it doesn't, then no.

With the first one... It's a bit trickier because you can have many different solutions. You can use `Reflection`, `Action`, `Func`, custom `delegate`s ...

(**IMHO**) So the "easy" way (if you have sh.. ton of methods) would be to use reflection and custom attributes, like so:

```
public class RandomCircleMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public RandomCircleMethodAttribute() : base() { }
}
```

And then assign this `Attribute` to methods you want to call. Then using [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), just get `MethodInfo` pointing to these methods and call them like so:

```
public class RandomCircleMethods
{
    [RandomCircleMethod]
    public void circleA() { //.. your logic here
    }

    [RandomCircleMethod]
    public void circleB() { //.. your logic here
    }

    // add as many as you want
}
```

Then inside your EntryPoint ( `Main(string[] args)` ) :

```
List<MethodInfo> methods = typeof(RandomCircleMethods).GetMethods().Where(method => Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(RandomCircleMethod))).ToList();
int selectedAction = new Random().Next(0, methods.Count);
methods[selectedAction].Invoke(new RandomCircleMethods(), null);
```

This way you don't have to create list of `Action`. But this is as good as your current way of making the job done.

I would stick to your current logic though, because it's less confusing than using reflection.